# I am not able to get which radio button is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button

I am trying to store 'yes' if a person clicks on the radio button with id - "negotiable" else stores 'no' if clicked on  id 'nonNegotiable' or when nothing is selected.

**Kotlin Function**

```
private fun addProduct(): HashMap<String, String?> {
        val sProductId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val sItemName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.itemName).text.toString()
        val sItemCategory = selectedValue
        val sDescription = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.description).text.toString()
        val sPrice = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.price).text.toString()
        val radioGroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radioGroup)
        var sNegotiable: String? = null

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            sNegotiable = if (checkedId == R.id.negotiable) {
                "yes"
            } else {
                "no"
            }
        }
        return hashMapOf(
            "productId" to sProductId,
            "itemName" to sItemName,
            "itemCategory" to sItemCategory,
            "description" to sDescription,
            "price" to sPrice,
            "negotiable" to sNegotiable
        )
```

**Xml code -**

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addProduct"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/negotiable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="@string/negotiable" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/nonNegotiable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="@string/non_negotiable" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

I am storing this in firebase firestore and it is storing null in negotiable.

Comment: this is async code. you shouldn't return map before it's clicked. it's not very clear why you need it but you. might want to have a callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setOnCheckedChangeListener`is an async function, code inside the listener is not executed immediately, so when you return the `HashMap`, `sNegotiable` might still be `null` because the listener may not have been triggered yet.

One way to handle this is by using a callback to update your `HashMap` after the `RadioGroup` selection changes. Here's an example:

```kotlin
private fun addProduct(callback: (HashMap<String, String?>) -> Unit) {
    val sProductId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val sItemName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.itemName).text.toString()
    val sItemCategory = selectedValue
    val sDescription = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.description).text.toString()
    val sPrice = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.price).text.toString()
    val radioGroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radioGroup)
    var sNegotiable: String? = null

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
        sNegotiable = if (checkedId == R.id.negotiable) {
            "yes"
        } else {
            "no"
        }

        // Call the callback with the updated HashMap
        callback.invoke(hashMapOf(
            "productId" to sProductId,
            "itemName" to sItemName,
            "itemCategory" to sItemCategory,
            "description" to sDescription,
            "price" to sPrice,
            "negotiable" to sNegotiable
        ))
    }
}

// Example of how to use the addProduct function with a callback
addProduct { hashMap ->
    // Now you can use the updated HashMap
    // For example, you can save it to Firebase Firestore here
    // firestore.collection("yourCollection").document("yourDocument").set(hashMap)
}
```

By using a callback, you ensure that the `HashMap` is updated after the `RadioGroup` selection changes and before you return it. Adjust this example according to your specific use case and how you interact with Firebase Firestore.

Comment: Good answer! But I hope I get the green checkmark myself :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're facing here is due to the fact that your function is probably returning waaaay before the click listener is registered, and calls you back.

Instead, you should make an effort to update whatever it is that you're trying to update with the `return hasMapOf(...)` call, probably in an async way as to avoid any complications.

Try to refactor your code to something like this instead:

```
interface Callback {
    fun onRadioButtonClicked(values: HashMap<String, String?>)
}

private fun addProduct(callback: Callback) {
        val sProductId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val sItemName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.itemName).text.toString()
        val sItemCategory = selectedValue
        val sDescription = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.description).text.toString()
        val sPrice = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.price).text.toString()
        val radioGroup = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radioGroup)
        var sNegotiable: String? = null

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            sNegotiable = if (checkedId == R.id.negotiable) {
                "yes"
            } else {
                "no"
            }
            callback(
                hashMapOf(
                    "productId" to sProductId,
                    "itemName" to sItemName,
                    "itemCategory" to sItemCategory,
                    "description" to sDescription,
                    "price" to sPrice,
                    "negotiable" to sNegotiable
                )
            )
        }
}
```

This way, you'll get notified every time a radio button is clicked, and therefore the data changes, and you'll be able to act accordingly every time that happens.  Of course, you'll want to unregister the callback once you're done, as to avoid having any memory leaks, or any other kind of unforeseen issue!